# C# WinForm - Compute Value Inside the DataGrid Rows Except The First Row[0]

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

Good day,

I want to compute all the rows from top to bottom except the first row which is counted as 0. Because my row[0] will show the total result of the rows.

Here's how it looks like.

```
_  _________  
0 | 100.00  | // Row 0
_  _________  
1 |  50.00  | // Row 1
_  _________  
2 |  50.00  | // Row 2
```

When the click event handler is click, the first row will be null at first.

```
_  ________  
0 |  0.00  | // Row 0
```

If I click the button for the second time, it will compute the rows[1] up to below and then execute the sum at the first row.

My Sample Code:

```
decimal totalCost; // outside the event handler
if (dgv.Rows.Count != 0)
{
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
      totalCost += Convert.ToDecimal(dgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
   }
   dgv.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = Convert.ToDecimal( totalCost ).ToString("##,###.00");
}
```

I am having a wrong value inside the row[0] cell[0]

Comment: If you don't want to include the first row, then don't include it: `for (i = 1;...`

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
decimal totalCost; // outside the event handler
if (dgv.Rows.Count != 0)
{
   for (int i = 1; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
      totalCost += Convert.ToDecimal(dgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
   }
   dgv.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = Convert.ToDecimal( totalCost ).ToString("##,###.00");
}
```